# Sequelize hooks (afterCreate. afterUpdate) in association (pivot, belongsToMany) not working

Tags: orm, associations, hook, sequelize.js

I'm building an API using Sequelize as the ORM. I wanted to incorporate some "listeners" in the core logic to check if certain values have changed and fire off some logic based on that.

One of my main concerns atm is a pivot table between customers and users. (BelongsToMany). The relation has some extra fields in the pivot like "is_admin" or "notify_user". This describes that a user is an admin for a certain customer, and if the system should notify this user on a customers action.

My API supports PATCHING of the pivot tables' data. Now what I want to do for example is if the is_admin value changes, fire off some other logic to update foo elsewhere.

All hooks work on the base object models (User and Customer). But none of my hooks are fired on the pivot object model.

Not sure if this is supported in Sequelize.

Thanks in advance

My relations are setup like this:

```
private static setupCustomerRelations(sq: Sequelize.Sequelize) {

    const user = sq.models['User'] || new UserRepo().getNewInstance().getModel();
    const customer = sq.models['Customer'] || new CustomerRepo().getNewInstance().getModel();
    const customerUsers = sq.models['customer_users'] || new CustomerUsersRepo().getNewInstance().getModel()
    const machine = sq.models['Machine'] || new MachineRepo().getNewInstance().getModel()

    customer.belongsToMany(user, {'through': customerUsers});
    user.belongsToMany(customer, {'through': customerUsers});

    // Machines
    machine.belongsTo(customer, {'foreignKey':'customer_id'});
    customer.hasMany(machine, {'foreignKey':'customer_id'});
}
```

And this customerUsers is a proper model

Comment: How are your `belongsToMany` associations defined? Is your pivot table a proper model or just defined as a string in the config of the association?

Comment: I will edit question above

Comment: Can you show a hook that isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

I've had luck with [Bulk hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/#model-hooks) on join tables. Try using `beforeBulkCreate` and `beforeBulkUpdate` on the join table's model.

```
CustomerUser.addHook('beforeBulkCreate', 'admin-only', async function(customerUsers) {
  for (const customerUser of customerUsers) {
    const user = await User.findById(customer);
    if (user.isAdmin) { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

Obviously this is going to produce tons of queries and you should think carefully about that and how to avoid that.